# Dead Poets Society

Tags: grammar

I wonder why there is no apostrophe in the film title "Dead Poets Society". Shouldn't it have been written as "***Dead Poets' Society***"?

Answer (score 3):

**Dead Poets Society** would be a society that concerns itself with dead poets - reading their works and discussing their lives.

**Dead Poets' Society** would be a society *for* dead poets - that is the members would be dead poets.

I haven't seen the movie, so I don't know for sure which is correct.

Comment: It is probably the former - people getting together to talk about dead poets, but I would be much more likely to watch if it featured Rimbaud and Dylan Thomas grumbling about "hipsters these days....."

Comment: I believe both of your answers are convincing. Thanks! By the way, it's an American drama film (1989) in which late Robin Williams plays the main role.

Comment: Except they got together not to talk about dead poets but to recite their (living) poems or poetry. And @M.N. although it is fine to say 'the late' Robin Williams, one does not have to, and we would more often just say Robin Williams in this context. This is because an "alive" Robin Williams plays (present tense) the role in the movie,

Comment: just like Humphrey Bogart plays (present tense) the main role in *Casablanca*.

Comment: It's actually an Australian film with a US setting. Peter Weir is the director.

Answer (score 0):

"Dead Poets Society" may mean that the society named "Dead poets" or they want to call that society using the name "Dead poets" Which must be reflecting the theme of the movie.